# Tomcat deploy context root via commandline

Tags: java, tomcat, command-line

How can I deploy my war file at / via commandline? The following does not work:

```
curl -X PUT --upload-file ROOT.war "http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/" -u 'admin:password'
```

It insteads gets deployed at /ROOT.war.

Thanks!

Comment: `ROOT.war` is actually the correct war filename for the root context (see [naming scheme](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming)) and its canonical context path is the empty string (not `/`).

Comment: Thanks! Mind posting it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working as it is supposed to work: the base file name of the empty context path is `ROOT` (see [naming scheme](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming)). Therefore a WAR file for the root context will be uploaded to `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/ROOT.war`.